# How to run django project on nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm trying to run my first Django project using nginx and uwsgi. And I faced with the problem with nginx. I get the message in the brouser "Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000". I'm following the instructions from this link  Everything is fine with uwsgi and installing nginx. Then I downloaded uwsgi_params file and created mysite_nginx.conf file as the instruction says.

Here's mysite_nginx.conf file:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
# server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
# the port your site will be served on
listen      8000;
# the domain name it will serve for
server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
charset     utf-8;

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
location /media  {
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/friends_plans/media;  # your Django      project's media files - amend as required
}

location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/friends_plans/static; # your Django  project's static files - amend as required
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the    uwsgi_params file you installed
}
}
```

It worked with server name "localhost" and port 8000 when I was checking uwsgi according to the intruction. I made the commands `sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ , python manage.py collectstatic , sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`. In my settinds.py: `STATIC_ROOT = "/home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/friends_plans/static/"`. The command about static files worked properly. But I can't set the connection with the server. Could you please tell me where I have a mistake and how to correct it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It looks like NginX is not listening to port 8000. What does the log say?

Comment: Is nginx running / reloaded? run `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` and try again.

Comment: I was trying to see the logs but I couldn't open the log file. I tried `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. First I gor "Permission denied". Then I tried `sudo nginx -t`, but it did't help, then I tried `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx;
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx;`, but now no reaction to the 1-st command.

Comment: In the instruction I used it is said to run `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`, I did this.

Comment: Running the command `sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log` shows that the error log file is empty.

Comment: Can you show your main nginx configuration file? It sholud be located directly in `/etc/nginx/`

Comment: I had a link for `mysite_nginx.conf`: `sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. But then made a copy of it `$ sudo cp ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/` and a link `$ sudo ln -sf ../sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. This worked. Thanks.